# Plot time series per millisecond

Tags: r, plot, time-series, milliseconds

I can't get my plot to show the points per millisecond. It always aggregates it all together per second. But I have data per millisecond. What am I doing wrong?

I have a data frame with:

```
                   time     x      y    z
2015-09-24 14:21:40.130  0.11  -0.19 1.54
2015-09-24 14:21:40.229  0.11  -0.19 1.54
2015-09-24 14:21:40.279  1.27  -0.55 1.69
2015-09-24 14:21:40.309  0.19   0.05 0.44
2015-09-24 14:21:40.342  1.15  -0.16 1.39
2015-09-24 14:21:40.426  0.03   0.88 0.12
```

The time column is POSIXct time

```
options(digits.secs=3)
data$time <- as.POSIXct(data$time, "%H:%M:%OS" ,tz = "GMT")
```

When I plot it `plot(data$time, data$z)` it takes all the points in one second and plots that on the same line. So if I plot only 4 seconds of the data frame it shows 4 stripes of points instead of a continuous distribution of the milliseconds it contains between the seconds.

I would like to see the points distributed in milliseconds.
I also tried `ggplot` but there it is the same.
Hopefully my question is a bit clear, for I can't post any image.

for image see: https://github.com/NieneB/rplot/blob/master/Rplot01.png

Comment: What are you using? `zoo`, `xts`, `ts` ?

Comment: Just  'plot {graphics}'

Comment: I mean your time series object; what is the class of your time series object?

Comment: It is a  `data.frame` with data$time as  `POSIXct`

Answer (score 2):

Part of the problem is scale. Millisecond differences aren't well separated when your scale covers minutes of data.  I've expanded your sample to include four data sets separated by several minutes and where each set lies within the same second as is suggested by the chart you reference in your link.  `ggplot` could be used to plot this as shown in the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
sp <- ggplot(cbind(data, DayHrMin=format(data$time,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), 
             aes(x=as.POSIXlt(time)$sec, y=z))
sp <- sp + geom_point()
sp <- sp + facet_wrap( ~ DayHrMin, scale="free_x")
plot(sp)
```

This generates the following chart:

[image]